# data name adding data html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, c3.js

Given my data names can be super long, I want to implement a tooltip when the user hover the data name, however, I can't find any documentation on adding custom tags to the generated data name html. One can add a class but not data tag.

Example
[image]

The way too long data name in that case. A tooltip would be perfect.

Comment: Do you mean you want to have a short data name but show its full length as a tooltip when hovered over?

Comment: Not necessarily, the tooltip content could be something different from the initial value. Meaning, I don't wanna crop the text and show the full length on hover. the data name could be "hello" and then on hover "It's a beautiful day today!"

Comment: All right, but you don't want to have shorter values tho?

Comment: Well, not really, because, the end goal is something like `'data' -> 'data comes from x,y,z'`, then  `'data (2)' -> 'data comes from x,y,z'`,  `'data (3)' -> 'data comes from x,y,z'`, etc... where x,y, z can be anything

Comment: Well you don't need a data attribute, you could target the elements by their class, which is unique based on the label name, for example, a label of "hello" can be targeted by `.c3-legend-item-hello`. Then you could embed a tooltip text that shows on hover using a custom JavaScript function

Comment: I thought about that, but I can have `n` number of classes, Id have to create a selector `c3-legend-item-{customId}` and then parse the name itself of the selector to find the id and then retransform it according to my parser. Kind of a pain to do.

Comment: yeah, you could create a function that loops through your columns but then again you need to assign the custom tooltip for each one separately. I think this problem requires a modification to the core C3 library, what about posting on the GitHub page? you might have better luck there

Comment: Can you clarify a little bit more? Specifically - the way I understood this question is that you have very long legend names (the way too long bit at the bottom of your donut chart is the legend), and instead of legend names you want a tooltip? Tooltips are already supported in c3. Or did you mean that you want your legend to be "hello" and hover the legend item and display "hello from america"?

Comment: I meant `Or did you mean that you want your legend to be "hello" and hover the legend item and display "hello from america"'`. It's true, c3 supports tooltip but on the actual graph not the legends that are under the chart. Imagine a dynamic toolbar where many options can be chosen and then a chart is loaded function of the options chosen. To understand the actual graph loaded(many can be), A long description is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I understood what you wanted :)

We can just use a couple extra functions in our `c3.generate` call and extend the library a bit, this will give you some more flexibility. Just define your long labels inside the `oninit` function.

Here is the jsFiddle, hover over the legend to see: 
https://jsfiddle.net/abacaj90/6v2tpft2/14/

```
function insertAfter(referenceNode, newNode) {
    referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}

function legendFollowMouse(e) {
  var x = e[0];
  var y = e[1];
    return {
    x: x - 50 + 'px',
    y: y + 20 + 'px'
  }
}

function createLegendTooltip() {
    var svg = this.svg[0][0];
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    div.className = 'c3-legend-tooltip-container';
    span.className = 'c3-legend-tooltip';

    div.appendChild(span);
    frag.appendChild(div);
    insertAfter(svg, frag);

    this.legendHoverNode = span;
}

function generateLegendHoverLabels(labels) {
  createLegendTooltip.call(this);
  var obj = {};
  this.data.targets.map(function(data, i) { 
     if(typeof labels[i] !== 'undefined') {
        obj[data.id] = data.id + ': ' + labels[i];
     }
  })
  return obj;
}


var chart = c3.generate({
  data: {
    columns: [
      ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
      ['data2', 20, 180, 240, 100, 190, 250],
      ['data3', 20, 180, 240, 100, 190, 250]
    ],
  },
  oninit: function() {
    // declare your extra long labels here
    var legendLongLabels = ['long content here, data3 doesnt have a tooltip!','even longer content here, you can style me with css!'];

    this.legendHoverContent = generateLegendHoverLabels.call(this, legendLongLabels);
  },
  legend: {
    item: {
      onmouseover: function (id) {
         // keep default behavior as well as our tooltip
         d3.select(this.svg[0][0]).classed('c3-legend-item-focused', true);

         if (!this.transiting && this.isTargetToShow(id)) {
           this.api.focus(id);
         }

         // if we defined the long labels, display them
         if (this.legendHoverContent.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
             var coords = legendFollowMouse(d3.mouse(this.svg[0][0]))
             this.legendHoverNode.parentNode.style.display = 'block';
             this.legendHoverNode.parentNode.style.top = coords.y;
             this.legendHoverNode.parentNode.style.left = coords.x;
             this.legendHoverNode.innerHTML = this.legendHoverContent[id];
         }
      },
      onmouseout: function (id) {
        // keep default behavior as well
        d3.select(this.svg[0][0]).classed('c3-legend-item-focused', false);
        this.api.revert();

        // just hide the tooltips
        this.legendHoverNode.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: That's really nice and well made. It'd be perfect if that was integrated at c3 core ! I'll prolly create a wrapper to hide the heavy lifting and keep the onInit. Thank you !

Comment: Thank you :) - yes something like this can be added and most of the helper functions would even be removed if it was integrated. I suppose if enough people need this I could do a pull req.

Answer (score 0):

**Temporary answer** while waiting for something better:

This is the input Data Im using.

```
var data = {
"data": [{
    "A": "1075.000000",
    "date": "01-03-2016"
}, {
    "A": "878.571429",
    "date": "01-04-2016"
}, {
    "A": "485.000000",
    "date": "04-03-2016"
}, {
    "A": "795.000000",
    "date": "05-03-2016"
}, {
    "A": "620.000000",
    "date": "06-03-2016"
}, {
    "A": "957.500000",
    "date": "07-03-2016"
}, {
    "name": "H1W",
    "A": "990.000000"
}, {
    "A": "950.000000",
    "date": "09-03-2016"
}, {
    "A": "680.000000",
    "date": "10-03-2016"
}, {
    "A": "1000.000000",
    "date": "17-03-2016"
}, {
    "A": "535.000000",
    "date": "18-02-2016"
}],
"name": "A",
"namePlus": {
    "location": "B or C or D or E",
    "vars": {
        "sizes": "Sizes: 2 or 3 or 5",
        "unitSizes": "Units Amount: (0 to 2) or (3 to 5)"
    }
}}
```

This is how I process the input

```
var tooltip = "<ul><li>" + data.name + "</li><li>" + data.namePlus.location + "</li>";
$.each(data.namePlus.vars, function (key, value) {
    tooltip += "<li>" + value + "</li>";
 });
 tooltip += "</ul>";

c3.generate({
            bindto: '#lineChart',
            data: {
                json: data.data,
                keys: {
                    x: 'date',
                    value: [data.name]
                },
                xFormat: '%d-%m-%Y',
                classes: {
                    value: 'HEY'
                }
            });

            $(".c3-legend-item-" + data.name).mouseover(function (e) {
                $(".myTooltip").html(tooltip).css({visibility: "visible"});
            });
            $(".c3-legend-item-" + data.name).mouseleave(function (e) {
                $(".myTooltip").html(tooltip).css({visibility: "hidden"});
            });
```

And this is the actual css

```
.myTooltip {
background-color: black;
border-radius: 6px;
color: #fff;
font-size: 12px;
height: 25px;
margin: auto;
opacity: 0.68;
padding: 5px 0;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
top: 14px;
visibility: hidden;
width: 50%;}
```